# Recommendations Bar opening over the main content area

Tags: progress-bar, facebook-recommendations

I have problem with positioning of FB recommendations bar. Last few days bar is opening over the main content area (near middle of page), instead in corner. I’ve noticed that this is happening on several other pages, not just mine. So is there any solution for this problem?